# Bubble Notification on Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

I have a project on Xamarin Forms with .Net Standard 2.0 and I need to create a have a blocking issue. At some point I go from my app to Google Map Navigation and I need a bubble(floating widget) like Facebook Messenger when Navigation it's open in order to go back to my app when the widget is clicked.

Do you have any example how to create this widget?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.  Can your provide a screenshot or link that demonstrates what you're trying to do?

Comment: A more detailed explanation would really help others understand what you are trying to achieve. If you can also show the attempt you have already made we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Pretty old, but this might get you started: http://www.spikie.be/post/2017/07/01/AndroidFloatingWidgetsInXamarin.html